# Can items and Tokens still be claimed from the Mansion even if the character is defeated?

Tags: resident-evil-deck-building-game

If a player explores the Mansion with more than one Explore (ie: +1 Explore from a Shotgun), they normally have the option to draw more than one card and resolve them both at the same time.  While this is fairly straightforward when both cards drawn are Infected, the situation when one of the cards is an Item or a Token is not quite as clear.

At what point would the Item/Token be resolved?  Is it immediately after the card is revealed, as would be the case if it was a single draw?  Or maybe it would be after the Infected itself is defeated.  Or maybe it's just after the Infected is battled, win or lose, so long as the player doesn't die.

I'm leaning towards the "just don't die" interpretation myself, but the rulebook is not particularly clear (I only have the base set to refer to, not sure if it's been clarified in the expansions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would apply the effect of any [Token][Item][Event], or any other Non-Infected card when it is revealed, before defeating or failing to defeat the infected. You resolve combat only after applying the effects of the Non-Infected cards.

The [official Rules](http://www.bandai.com/residentevil/pdf/RE_RuleBk.pdf) say:

> **Non-Infected Cards**
>
> Sometimes Events can be found when Exploring the Mansion instead of an Infected. In this case, When the Event is revealed, perform the effect listed on the card.

There is also the [Comprehensive FAQ](http://www.bandai.com/residentevil/forum/showthread.php?274-Comprehensive-FAQ) (which appears to be answered mostly by Alex_Bandai, who I assume is a Bandai Representative):

> **If I am defeated can I still collect Tokens or Items reveled?**
>
> Yes, you collect all tokens and items as soon as you discover them.